# What is the next step on the infected files and errors?

Tags: 14.10, clamav

I scanned my computer for viruses by using `clamav`: `sudo clamscan -r --bell -i /`.  I received the following result:

> LibClamAV Warning: cli_scanxz: decompress file size exceeds limits - only scanning 27262976 bytes
>
> LibClamAV Warning: cli_scanxz: decompress file size exceeds limits - only scanning 27262976 bytes
>
> LibClamAV Warning: cli_scanxz: decompress file size exceeds limits - only scanning 27262976 bytes
>
> /home/beck/Documents/from flash/unsorted/autorun.inf: INF.Autorun.Gen FOUND
>
> LibClamAV Warning: fmap_readpage: pread fail: asked for 4077 bytes @ offset 19, got 0
>
> WARNING: Can't open file /sys/module/ipt_REJECT/uevent: Permission denied
>
> LibClamAV Warning: fmap_readpage: pread fail: asked for 4077 bytes @ offset 19, got 0
>
> LibClamAV Warning: fmap_readpage: pread fail: asked for 4093 bytes @ offset 3, got 0
>
> LibClamAV Warning: fmap_readpage: pread fail: asked for 4094 bytes @ offset 2, got 0
>
> WARNING: Can't open file /sys/module/nf_conntrack_tftp/uevent: Permission denied
>
> LibClamAV Warning: fmap_readpage: pread fail: asked for 4094 bytes @ offset 2, got 0

```
----------- SCAN SUMMARY -----------  
Known viruses: 3775271 
Engine version: 0.98.6 
Scanned directories: 98517 
Scanned files: 1144928 
Infected files: 2 Total errors: 19018 
Data scanned: 51350.64 MB 
Data read: 69028.91 MB (ratio 0.74:1) 
Time: 10960.993 sec (182 m 40 s)
```

I succeeded deleting the "autorun" virus. But I cannot find the other virus.  So, what should I do with the infected file and the errors?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, all these errors are happening because `clamscan` is scanning `/` and for scan `/` you need to execute it as root (i.e. `sudo clamscan -r --bell -i /`), otherwise it will fail because it hasn't permission to read many files.

When it finished, please update your question with the path and name of the infected files and I'll update my answer with what can you do with them.

Comment: I followed you advice and received the following summary

>Known viruses: 3775271
Engine version: 0.98.6
Scanned directories: 98517
Scanned files: 1144928
Infected files: 2
Total errors: 19018
Data scanned: 51350.64 MB
Data read: 69028.91 MB (ratio 0.74:1)
Time: 10960.993 sec (182 m 40 s)

Comment: Also there were the following information which may be helpful:

LibClamAV Warning: cli_scanxz: decompress file size exceeds limits - only scanning 27262976 bytes
/home/tux/Documents/from flash/unsorted/autorun.inf: INF.Autorun.Gen FOUND
LibClamAV Warning: fmap_readpage: pread fail: asked for 4077 bytes @ offset 19, got 0
WARNING: Can't open file /sys/module/ipt_REJECT/uevent: Permission denied

There were more warnings similar to these ones, except the one which, I think, shows the virus.  I cannot add them due to character restrictions

Comment: Edit your post and paste it.

Comment: I posted the new summary in the original questions above